# TSQL - Query help for generating incremental sequence numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help on a query to generate a two incremental values on below table.

Both the `BatchNo` and `BatchSequenceNo` should begin at 1.

The `BatchSequenceNo` should increment by 1, up to 500 rows.

At 501 row, the `BatchNo` should be incremented by 1 (ie BatchNo = 2) and 
the `BatchSequenceNo` should reset to 1.

`BatchNo` values needs to incremented by 1, for every 500 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #tblBatch
(
    BatchId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Sname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    BatchNo int,
    BatchSequenceNo int
)

---Load some sample data
INSERT INTO #tblBatch(Sname)
    SELECT TOP 2010 
        'A -SampleText-' + CAST(row_number() over(order by t1.number) as varchar) as N
    FROM
        master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN
        master..spt_values t2
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? One great way to avoid some of your coding is to use Sequences (from sql server 2012). Give it a try

Comment: Note that the various answers that calculate values based on `Row_Number()` will have the feature that `BatchNo` and `BatchSequenceNo` will shift around if rows are deleted. Aducci's answer will provide stable results based on the primary key for the row.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to base your `BatchNo`/`BatchSequenceNo` numbers on your `BatchId` using calculated columns

```
CREATE TABLE #tblBatch(
   BatchId  INT   NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Sname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   BatchNo as (BatchId-1) / 500 + 1,
   BatchSequenceNo as BatchId % 500
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo and division to do this.

```
    Select 
CAST(((row_number() over(order by t1.number) / 500)+1) as int) as BatchNo,
CAST(((row_number() over(order by t1.number)-1 % 500)+1) as int) as BatchSequenceNo 
    from   master..spt_values t1
           cross join master..spt_values t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use division and modulo operators to get the batchno and batchsequenceno respectively.

```
Select top 2010 
 1+(row_number() over(order by t1.number)-1)/500 as batch_no
,'A -SampleText-'+cast(1+(row_number() over(order by t1.number)-1)%500 as varchar(100)) as N
from master..spt_values t1
cross join master..spt_values t2
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/BHQ82910)

Answer (score 0):

rextester: http://rextester.com/GUSA26703

```
create table #tblbatch (
    batchid  int   not null identity(1,1) primary key
  , sname varchar(50) not null
  , BatchSequenceNo int
  , BatchNo int
);

insert into #tblBatch(Sname,BatchSequenceNo,BatchNo)
Select top 2010 
    Sname = 'A -SampleText-'+cast(row_number() over(order by t1.number) as varchar)
  , BatchSequenceNo = ((row_number() over(order by t1.number) -1)%500)+1
  , BatchNo = ((row_number() over(order by t1.number) -1)/500)+1
from   master..spt_values t1
  cross join master..spt_values t2

select 
    minN=min(batchid)
  , maxN=max(batchid)
  , minBatchSequenceNo=min(BatchSequenceNo)
  , maxBatchSequenceNo=max(BatchSequenceNo)
  , BatchCount=count(*)
  , BatchNo
  from #tblbatch
  group by BatchNo
  order by BatchNo
```

results in:

```
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| minN | maxN  | minBatchSequenceNo | maxBatchSequenceNo | BatchCount | BatchNo |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
|    1 |   500 |                  1 |                500 |        500 |       1 |
|  501 |  1000 |                  1 |                500 |        500 |       2 |
| 1001 |  1500 |                  1 |                500 |        500 |       3 |
| 1501 |  2000 |                  1 |                500 |        500 |       4 |
| 2001 |  2010 |                  1 |                 10 |         10 |       5 |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
```

rextester setup: http://rextester.com/UWIAU84781

```
with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, d as (
        /* start from 0 */
  --select n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1 
        /* start from 1 */
  select n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo    
      cross join n as [tenk]  
      --cross join n as [hundredk]
      --cross join n as mega
) 
, batch as (
  select 
      n
    /* start from 0 */
    --, BatchSequenceNo=(n%500)+1
    --, BatchNo=(n/500)+1
    /* start from 1 */
    , BatchSequenceNo=((n-1)%500)+1
    , BatchNo=((n-1)/500)+1
    from d
)
select 
    minN=min(n)
  , maxN=max(n)
  , minBatchSequenceNo=min(BatchSequenceNo)
  , maxBatchSequenceNo=max(BatchSequenceNo)
  , BatchCount=count(*)
  , BatchNo
  from batch
  group by BatchNo
  order by BatchNo
```

results in:

```
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
| minN | maxN  | minBatchSequenceNo | maxBatchSequenceNo | BatchCount | BatchNo |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
|    1 |   500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       1 |
|  501 |  1000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       2 |
| 1001 |  1500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       3 |
| 1501 |  2000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       4 |
| 2001 |  2500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       5 |
| 2501 |  3000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       6 |
| 3001 |  3500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       7 |
| 3501 |  4000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       8 |
| 4001 |  4500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |       9 |
| 4501 |  5000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      10 |
| 5001 |  5500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      11 |
| 5501 |  6000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      12 |
| 6001 |  6500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      13 |
| 6501 |  7000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      14 |
| 7001 |  7500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      15 |
| 7501 |  8000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      16 |
| 8001 |  8500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      17 |
| 8501 |  9000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      18 |
| 9001 |  9500 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      19 |
| 9501 | 10000 |          1         |                500 |        500 |      20 |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you like this:

```
WITH cte_Tally AS (
    SELECT  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n) --10
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n) -- 100
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n) -- 1,000
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n) -- 10,000
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n % 500 ORDER BY n) AS [Sequence], n % 500 AS [Sequence], n 
FROM cte_Tally
ORDER BY n
```

Comment: This is horrible.  Worse than brute force to use the combinations of cross joins to give you enough rows.  We have mathematical operators in SQL.  You can multiply something by 10 like this: `* 10`